# Discord bot automatically switches itself off as well as performs really slowly during certain parts of the day

Tags: discord, discord.js

We have a Discord bot which runs perfectly fine 90% of the time; it is hosted on a VPS.

The bot occasionally switches itself off even though the VPS is still online; either it switches itself off or it performs extremely slowly. When we see this issue occur, we restart the VPS and the bot comes online but doesn't respond to any commands for a while; sometimes it will respond to a ping with over 50k ms. After it has been online for a while, it will switch itself off while the VPS is still online and even while the bot is appearing offline, it sometimes sends extremely delayed responses to the ping command with over 100k ms. This only occurs during certain parts of the day.

It is definitely not the code because we are running the exact same files with the exact same code on a test bot which has zero issues. It cannot be the host/VPS either as when we run the public bot on various different hosts, the same issue occurs.

Information about what the bot does, etc, can be found [here](https://discordbots.org/bot/582537632991543307).

Update:  Sharding has resolved the issue.

Comment: with no more information, and assuming it can't be the code or the host, do you have any hosted database that could slow the whole app down ?

Comment: The databases are stored together with the bot's coded files, it is not externally hosted. You may get a better interpretation of what information the databases store by referring to the link given in the original post which gives an insight on the functionality of the bot.

Comment: Is it possible that the databases are slowing the app down, for whatever reason ? If your bot is present on a high amount of servers, another possibility is that you exceed discord api rate limits. (https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits). You could try to monitor this to see if it could be the cause of your bot slowing down

Comment: Those are both possibilities for slowing it down; however, I don't believe either of those could be the reason as to why the bot is switching itself off and at times, refusing to start.

Comment: A. How are you running the bot within the VPS? You mentioned that you restart the VPS and the bot comes online, so I'm assuming a shell script to run on startup? B. Are there any errors in the console when this happens? If the bot is having connection issues, you might also see your `reconnecting` event be emitted. C. When you say the client's ping is displayed as extremely high, are you calculating the time between the message sent and when it's received, or using [`Client.ping`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=ping)?

Comment: A) Startup script.
B) No errors, just logs from debugging.
C) Client.